# Vertices of a regular polygon in the plane with irrational coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons

Today I was trying to solve a problem about triangulation and I came with this

> For which $n≥3$ is it possible to draw a regular $n$-gon in the plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$) such that all vertices have irrational coordinates?

My approach was assume WLOG irrational vertices $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$. Then, if $(x,y)$ is a rotation of $(x_0, y_0)$ in $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ about origin, we have
$$(x,y)=\left(x_0\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}-y_0\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}, x_0\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}+y_0\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$$
And my idea was analize that expression, but I do not know how. Is there a best approach? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I suspect you are over thinking this.  Start with a regular polygon whose vertex coordinates are algebraic. Now perturb them, either by scaling or translation.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct. Here is how to complete. Only countable number of rotations will give polygons which have rational vertices (do you know how to show that?). So almost all rotations will give polygons where all vertices are irrational (the same argument works if "irrational" is replaced by "transcendental").

Comment: Why almost? I know square is the only polygon that can have rational coordinates, so I suppose every polygon can have irrational coordinates, is that true?

Comment: See the question. I answered the question in OP.

Comment: I read wrong, my apologies!